# Rewrite txt file into other encoding

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, cp1250, iso-8859-2

I have a problem. I want to rewrite txt file into other txt file, but with other encoding. I must implement conversion to Unicode, iso-8859 and windows-1250.

I must write it in c++. 
Can anyone help me with this topic? How to start coding this?

Best regards!

Comment: First, you need to look up those encodings and setup conversion tables for them. Then, open the file, read it byte by byte, converting each byte through a table lookup, and writing it out to the output file.

Comment: What encoding has file created in notepad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is perfectly capable of doing string conversions for you. Read data from the source file and pass it to [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072.aspx) specifying the source codepage, then pass that output to [`WideCharToMultiByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130.aspx) specifying the target codepage and write that output to the target file.

BTW, next question state up front that you're working on Windows only. Don't put  useful information like that in a comment.

Comment: Hi! Sory for this (skip info about OS). I write this pastebin.com/p5cCtZfx . When I open output file, notepad++ show me ANSI as UTF-8 (right bottom), but when I convert string with polish letters it shows only a square on polish letter place.. For second, it only convert into utf-8? I don't see in documentation any info about iso-8859 and windows-1250.

Comment: @user3025978: Sorry, I have no idea what that all means. "Show ANSI as UTF-8"? UTF-8 is an 8 bits encoding of Unicode, and ANSI is the American National Standards Institute (who did not create UTF-8). ISO-8859 is a standard which contains 15 character sets. Most of those do not contain polish characters, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by getting a good in-depth knowledge of this encoding formats, I would create some encoding conversion tables, and convert byte by byte. Also, it sounds like you are going to be dealing with different operating systems, so keep an eye out for endianness.

Here's a good link to get you started [Encoding for Programmers](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

EDT#1: Here is another link that goes a little more in depth on the [subject of character encoding in windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374083%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Here you can find functions and macros that can help you building your application.

Comment: Hi, thanks fot response. I will write it only to WindowsOS. Where can I found this conversion tables? Or how can I prepare this table?